# Queue interactive commands and attend to then in sequence

Tags: shell, subshell, interactive

I want to have a script that adds commands to some kind of queue. I then want to run those commands interactively one at a time.  More commands should be able to be added to the queue while I'm running the queue.

The commands I'm queuing run a tui interface and fail if they detect a non-interactive shell.

I've tried to find something that works like this but all the queue programs I can find assume the command are non-interactive. I've considered `batch`, `nq`, `tsp`, but as far as I can tell they don't work for my use case.

Any help would be appreciated. This seems like something that must have been solved somewhere, I just don't know how to find that information.

Comment: I ended up writing a python script that adds each command to a file, and another script that reads the files in order of creation and executes the commands interactively.